# Can i run Get-WindowsFeature PowerShell Command on Windows?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am trying to disable unnecessary features on windows 10 to optimize the os performance. I thought of creating Powershell DSC Configuration, refer the Windows Feature Resource inside it and disable the features i want.

To mention the feature name i have to run the Get-WindowsFeature command and see what features are there.But that command is not available in my powershell.I did some research and i got to know that Get-WindowsFeature will only work on Windows Server. Is this true?

So what Command i have to run to get the list of features on Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online
```

would give the list of features available in Windows. For more refer [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps)

Comment: I have already tried this. As mentioned in the documentation, i thought it is only listing optional features. Is there any difference as such?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where FeatureName -Match ".*RAT.*" | Format-Table -Autosize

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [script](https://www.scconfigmgr.com/2018/11/27/remove-built-in-apps-for-windows-10-version-1809/) for removing Built-In apps for Windows 10 by the scconfigmgr guys. In my experience, removing these unused apps has greatly improved performance, particularly when a new profile is built on the machine.

Essentially, it uses the `Get-AppxPackage` command to identify and then remove built-in apps which you might not want.

EDIT

In addition to the above, you can also query WMI to get what Features are enabled using the Win32_OptionalFeature class.

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_OptionalFeature where InstalledState = '1'"
```

Everything with an 'InstalledState' of '1' means it's currently installed.